# Too little available RAM in Asus Vivobook 15 X512DA (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, memory, asus-laptop

I'm totally aware that some ram has to remain non-usable for the user, as the system needs it.

Is it normal to have less than 75% of the RAM usable? If no, is there a way, tweak or hack that might help me with this? (without changing OS)

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is totally fine and no need to worry about. You still have 8 GB of Ram and you will still be able to use it completely without any performance drop.

This might be of some help:-

Click Start , type **msconfig** in the Search programs and files box, and then click msconfig in the Programs list.

In the System Configuration window, click **Advanced** options on the **Boot tab**.

Click to clear the **Maximum memory** check box, and then click **OK**.

**Restart the computer**.

This should fix the problem if you checked maximum memory option in msconfig.

Comment: i saw a youtube video with this approach, didn´t work

Answer (score 0):

Unless you f*cked up and installed windows 32 bit (i see you did not) often the missing ram is reserved to the integrated video card.
Some bios allow you to change how much memory is reserved to the video card. Unless you plan on play games or run heavy loads on the card then 256MB is plenty enough

Comment: unfortunately, my bios doesn´t show that option